# HTML Div won't stay under Div that is above it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two divs that act like two rows; one on top of the other spanning the width of the screen.  Each row contains an image and a title.  Mybe a snippet instead of a fiddle will help.  This is the "Good" Layout:

```css
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.float-left > * {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;  /*960px;*/
}

#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

    .main-content {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

header {
}

    .main-row {
        min-height: 85px;
        background: linear-gradient(#d2d2d9, #efeeef, white);
    }

    .menu-row {
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: #2983be;
    }

    .menu {
        min-height: 50px;
        max-width: 300px;
        background-color: #a5fa06;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-top: 10px; 
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main-row">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <img class="icon" style="float: left; " src="//placehold.it/50x80" alt="logo image" />
                    <label style="float: left; font-size: large; "><h1>My system</h1></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-row">
            <div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <label style="font-size: medium; "><h2>Home</h2></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

However when I include float-left, the bottom div moves upward.  See the [Fiddle of "Good" layout here](https://jsfiddle.net/pdlarue/n4nv5w3L/) and when I try to add the image using float-left, see the ["Moved" layout here](https://jsfiddle.net/pdlarue/89fd8e60/).  As you can see the bottom div moves up and the Home title displays under the bottom div.

I'm inserting the snippet here to show how the div moves:

```css
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.float-left > * {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;  /*960px;*/
}

#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

    .main-content {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

header {
}

    .main-row {
        min-height: 85px;
        background: linear-gradient(#d2d2d9, #efeeef, white);
    }

    .menu-row {
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: #2983be;
    }

    .menu {
        min-height: 50px;
        max-width: 300px;
        background-color: #a5fa06;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-top: 10px; 
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main-row">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <img class="icon" style="float: left; " src="//placehold.it/50x80" alt="logo image" />
                    <label style="float: left; font-size: large; "><h1>My system</h1></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-row">
            <div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="float-left">
                    <div style="width: 50px height: 50px;">
                        <img class="icon" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 50%; " src="//placehold.it/50x50" alt="home icon" />
                    </div>
                    <label style="float: left; font-size: medium; "><h2>Home</h2></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

How do I get the bottom div to stay under the first div?

Comment: If you don't want float behavior, don't use `float`.

Comment: But both the image and the text need to be beside each other.  That's why I'm using the float-left...in both blocks.

Comment: You can't see the icons in the fiddle (I couldn't get that working) but the first block works as expected, whereas the second block doesn't stay underneath the first block.

Comment: @Patricia There are image hosting services you can use like [imgur](https://imgur.com/).  Otherwise, you can base64 encode your images: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/gtcbygbe/. You can also just use a placeholder of the same dimensions: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/gtcbygbe/1/.  Regardless, can you adapt that fiddle to better reflect the original code?  Right now the image doesn't conform to any set width or height and overflows its container.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - I updated the snippets to contain placeholers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) You need to float the elements *inside*  `.float-left`,  not `.float-left` itself, so add this:

```
.float-left > * {
  float: left;
}
```

2.) and your `.menu` rule has a `max-width` setting which prevents it to get any wider than 150px. Erase that.

https://jsfiddle.net/v3vo37v7/2/

Here is also a snippet where additionally I reset the margin of h1 and h2 in the header to 0 to avoid their default vertical offset:

```css
html {
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header, footer, hgroup,
nav, section {
    display: block;
}

.float-left * {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.clear-fix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1, h2, h3,
h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

h5, h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

    h5 a:link, h5 a:visited, h5 a:active {
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


/* main layout
----------------------------------------------------------*/
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;  /*960px;*/
}

#body {
    background-color: #efeeef;
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

    .main-content {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

header {
}

    .main-row {
        min-height: 85px;
        background: linear-gradient(#d2d2d9, #efeeef, white);
    }

    .menu-row {
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: #2983be;
    }

    .menu {
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: #a5fa06;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        padding-top: 10px; 
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
}
header h1, header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="main-row">
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <img class="icon" style="float: left; " src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/13U6WdvWQhfUF_8qJ8BLKJpLQCPtNgMKZ/view?usp=sharing" alt="logo image" />
                    <label style="float: left; font-size: large; "><h1>My system</h1></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-row">
            <div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <img class="icon" style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 50%; " src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NAbtOJAariTJatGCcBEY48sR_gyKGMb-/view?usp=sharing" alt="home icon" />
                        <label style="float: left; font-size: medium; "><h2>Home</h2></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: That didn't stop the menu bar from jumping up instead of staying under the main bar but both got me closer to what I want.  See added image in question.  :-(

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but note the snippet I added.